# How can I arrange the rows and the columns in Spark using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, text, rows

I want from a text file in format:

```
first line
column1;column2;column3
column1;column2;column3
last line
```

to convert it into DataFrame without the first and the last line
I have skippet the first and the last line but then I become the rest text in one row and onw column
How can I arrange the rows?
I have also a schema for my DataFrame

```
var textFile = sc.textFile("*.txt")
val header = textFile.first()
val total = textFile.count()
var rows = textFile.zipWithIndex().filter(x => x._2 < total - 1).map(x => x._1).filter(x => x !=  header)

val schema = StructType(Array(
  StructField("col1", IntegerType, true),
  StructField("col2", StringType, true),
  StructField("col3", StringType, true),
  StructField("col4", StringType, true)
))
```

Comment: You should split the rest of the text with ; and then convert them Row and apply the schema to create the dataframe

Comment: yes, I have done it:
     import spark.implicits._
    val rowss = rows.map(x => {val m = x.split(","); Row(m(0), m(1), m(2), m(3))})
val df = rowss.toDF().show()

but toDF() is not working..

Comment: Your data contains ; and not ,

Comment: with ; is still not working
I also tried with spark.createDataFrame(rowRDD, schema), but I become a lot of errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be doing the following (commented for clarity)

```
//creating schema
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
val schema = StructType(Array(
  StructField("col1", StringType, true),
  StructField("col2", StringType, true),
  StructField("col3", StringType, true)
))

//reading text file and finding total lines
val textFile = sc.textFile("*.txt")
val total = textFile.count()

//indexing lines for filtering the first and the last lines
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
val rows = textFile.zipWithIndex()
    .filter(x => x._2 != 0 && x._2 < total - 1)
  .map(x => Row.fromSeq(x._1.split(";").toSeq))   //converting the lines to Row of sequences

//finally creating dataframe
val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rows, schema)
df.show(false)
```

which should give you

```
+-------+-------+-------+
|col1   |col2   |col3   |
+-------+-------+-------+
|column1|column2|column3|
|column1|column2|column3|
+-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: It's working, thank you!